# Cannot see the data immediately into a div element from an observable

Tags: angular

Can you please tell me where I get my code wrong? I have an observable from a qrScanner. I get the data from that observable then put it in a variable that I want to show in the html. If I use an alert, as soon as I get out of the alert, the data that I got from the observable is rendered in the html. But if I don't use an alert, the data from the observable is not rendered immediately but as soon as I click on the 'scan' button, the observable is posted. Why is this so? Please see my code below:

**.ts**

```
scannedData: string = '';
scan() {
    this.qrScanner.prepare()
      .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
        if(status.authorized) {
          this.qrScanner.enableLight();

          let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
            this.scannedData = text; // I place the value onto this var
            this.qrScanner.hide();
            scanSub.unsubscribe();
          });

          this.qrScanner.resumePreview();

          this.qrScanner.show();

        } else if (status.denied) {
          this.presentAlert('Access to camera is permanently denied.');
            // camera permission was permanently denied
           // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
           // then they can grant the permission from there
        } else {
          this.presentAlert('Access to camera is denied.');
          // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
        }
      })
      .catch((e: any) => this.presentAlert('Error: '+e));
}
```

**.html**

```
<div>
    <button ion-button block (click)="scan()">Scan</button>
    <div>
      <br>
      <span><h3>{{ scannedData }}</h3></span> <=== I do not see the observable until I press the 'scan' button again
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not very clear. Do you mean that data does  not show when you press the scan button once if you don't have the alert first?

Comment: The data does not show in the html when I press the scan. But if I alert it first, I get the data and when I close the alert, that's the time I get it in the html

Comment: You could try forcing change detection again with ChangeDetectorRef as a workaround after assigning the variable.

Comment: I would like to try that only I don't know how to do that. Also, I am using Ionic. I don't know if it would work.

Comment: I added an answer showing you how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, try forcing angular to detect changes.

**component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
 { //...}

scan()
{ //...

 let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => {
        this.scannedData = text;
        this.qrScanner.hide();
        scanSub.unsubscribe();
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You've introduced a new knowledge to me. I didn't know that there's such a method. This 'ChangeDetectorRef' is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because pressing the button runs the `scan()` function, which is what retrieves `scannedData` from your service. Until you press it, `scannedData` has the default value that you assigned to it at the beginning (an empty string).

If you want to retrieve that variable as soon as the component is rendered, you have to move the logic inside `ngOnInit`.

Comment: It is in the same component. Both of it is in the HomeComponent.

Comment: What I mean is that your scan() function doesn't execute until you call it, and right now your only way to call seems to be by pressing the button.

Comment: Yes. But as soon as I click on the scan, I get the result and place it in the variable and that means that variable is not empty anymore and that should be reflected in the html.